# Query shows results when search entry is partial, not when it's a literally database entry

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

My code works almost completely fine:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT BOEK_TITEL AS boektitel, BOEK_AUTEUR AS auteur, BOEK_GENRE as genre, BOEK_JAAR as jaar, BOEK_PAGINAS AS paginas, BOEK_TAG1 AS tag1, BOEK_TAG2 AS tag2, BOEK_TAG3 AS tag3 FROM b_boek WHERE BOEK_TITEL LIKE '%". $search ."%' ORDER BY BOEK_TITEL");
```

For example, when the book's title = Bloedband, and I search for 'Bloed', 'band', ban', etc., the book is part of the shown results.

If I search for  'Bloedband', it's not shown.

It's probably related to my wildcards, but can't seem to fix it.

Comment: Potential injection vulnerability. Where and how is `$search` defined?

Comment: I agree with @Watilin... do not simply throw some random value into the query, use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Answer (score -1):

I'd just adjust your original query to check for an exact match as well with an `OR` clause:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT BOEK_TITEL AS boektitel, BOEK_AUTEUR AS auteur, BOEK_GENRE as genre, BOEK_JAAR as jaar, BOEK_PAGINAS AS paginas, BOEK_TAG1 AS tag1, BOEK_TAG2 AS tag2, BOEK_TAG3 AS tag3 FROM b_boek WHERE BOEK_TITEL LIKE '%". $search ."%' OR BOEK_TITEL = '". $search ."' ORDER BY BOEK_TITEL");
```

Comment: @Michael, sounds like the using the or statement with an additional exact comparison will be your best bet then